# Applying google_logging_project_sink resource fails in terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am trying to `terraform apply` the following resource (the `plan` command succeeds)

```
resource "google_logging_project_sink" "my_logs_sink" {
  count                  = var.enable_my_log_sinks ? 1 : 0
  name                   = "cloudstorage-sink-${google_project.my.id}"
  destination            = "storage.googleapis.com/${module.log_sink_bucket.name}"
  project                = google_project.my.id
  unique_writer_identity = true
}
```

Τhe `module.log_sink_bucket` has already been created.

`apply` fails as follows:

```
│ Error: googleapi: got HTTP response code 404 with body: <!DOCTYPE html>
│ <html lang=en>
│   <meta charset=utf-8>
│...
│   <p>The requested URL <code>/v2/projects/projects/my_project_id/sinks?alt=json&amp;prettyPrint=false&amp;uniqueWriterIdentity=true</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
│
│
│   with google_logging_project_sink.my_logs_sink[0],
│   on log_sinks.tf line 17, in resource "google_logging_project_sink" "my_logs_sink":
│   17: resource "google_logging_project_sink" "my_logs_sink" {
}
```